# SQL Count where relationship Doesn't Exist

Tags: sql, relationships

I have a 3 Tables, one of which contains a list of incidents, another a list of users and a final one which contains the relationships between the incidents and users. There can be multiple users of differing types related to the incident (affected user or assigned to user, each of which has it's own relationship class) I trying to produce a query which will show the amount of incidents assigned to each user and also incidents that have no assigned to user. I have the following query for getting the list of users:

```
SELECT MTV_System$Domain$User.DisplayName as Analyst, COUNT(MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) AS Incidents
FROM RelationshipView
INNER JOIN MTV_System$Domain$User ON RelationshipView.TargetEntityId=MTV_System$Domain$User.BaseManagedEntityId
INNER JOIN MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident ON RelationshipView.SourceEntityId=MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident.BaseManagedEntityId
WHERE RelationshipView.RelationshipTypeId='15E577A3-6BF9-6713-4EAC-BA5A5B7C4722'  AND RelationshipView.IsDeleted='0' AND  MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident.Status_785407A9_729D_3A74_A383_575DB0CD50ED = '5E2D3932-CA6D-1515-7310-6F58584DF73E'

GROUP BY MTV_System$Domain$User.DisplayName
```

However this does not allow me to see how many incidents do not have a user. I have created this query which subtracts the number of incidents from the number with a relationship

```
Select (Select COUNT(MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) FROM MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident
WHERE MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident.Status_785407A9_729D_3A74_A383_575DB0CD50ED = '5E2D3932-CA6D-1515-7310-6F58584DF73E') -
(SELECT COUNT(MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C)
FROM RelationshipView
INNER JOIN MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident ON RelationshipView.SourceEntityId=MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident.BaseManagedEntityId
WHERE RelationshipView.RelationshipTypeId='15E577A3-6BF9-6713-4EAC-BA5A5B7C4722'  AND RelationshipView.IsDeleted='0' AND  MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident.Status_785407A9_729D_3A74_A383_575DB0CD50ED = '5E2D3932-CA6D-1515-7310-6F58584DF73E'
) AS 'Incidents'
```

However this is presented as a separate query as opposed to being a value of 'Unassigned' in the previous results.

How would I combine the 2 queries to get a result which looks like this:

```
Analyst    | No Incidents
Bob        |     5
Dave       |     4
Unassigned |     6
```

Thanks

Comment: Horrible column names, how can you work with such names?

Comment: They're not my column names, they are microsofts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `left join` to get things that are not matched.  For this, you want to start with the `Incident` table, because that has everything you want to keep.  The big subtlety is moving the conditions from the `where` clause to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT u.DisplayName as Analyst, 
       COUNT(r.SourceEntityId) AS Incidents
FROM MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident i LEFT JOIN
     RelationshipView r
     ON r.SourceEntityId = i.BaseManagedEntityId AND
        r.RelationshipTypeId = '15E577A3-6BF9-6713-4EAC-BA5A5B7C4722'  AND
        r.IsDeleted ='0'LEFT JOIN
     MTV_System$Domain$User u
     ON r.TargetEntityId = u.BaseManagedEntityId         
WHERE i.Status_785407A9_729D_3A74_A383_575DB0CD50ED = '5E2D3932-CA6D-1515-7310-6F58584DF73E'
GROUP BY u.DisplayName
```

Note I also added table aliases.  These make the query much easier to write and to read.

EDIT:

I think you want:

```
SELECT COALESCE(u.DisplayName, 'Not Assigned') as Analyst, 
       COUNT(r.SourceEntityId) AS Incidents
. . .
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works perfectly. Is there any way of changing NULL to read unassigned instead?

Comment: @Alex, you mean like this coalesce(column, 'read unassigned')?